# How did Rambam understand "an Eye for an Eye"?

Tags: rambam, moreh-nevuchim

The RamBam, in the [More Nevuhim 3;41](https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed%2C_Part_3.41.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) write :

> ...
>
> עונש כל חוטא לזולתו בכלל – שיעשה בו כמו שעשה בשוה, אם הזיק בגוף ינזק בגופו, ואם הזיק בממון ינזק בממונו. ויש לבעל הממון למחול ולהקל. ...  **ומי שחיסר איבר יחוסר איבר; ״כאשר יתן מום באדם כן ינתן בו״. [ולא תטריד רעיונך בהיותנו עונשים הנה בממון, כי הכונה עתה לתת סיבת הפסוקים ולא סיבת דברי התלמוד. ועם כל זה יש לי במה שאמר בו התלמוד דעת ישמע פנים בפנים**].

> The punishment of him who sins against his neighbour consists in the general rule that there shall be done unto him exactly as he has done: if he injured any one personally, he must suffer personally; if he damaged the property of his neighbour, he shall be punished by loss of property. But the person whose property has been damaged should be ready to resign his claim totally or partly. ...  **And he who mutilated a limb of his neighbour, must himself lose a limb. “As he hath caused a blemish in a man, so shall it be done to him again” (Lev. 24:20). You must not raise an objection from our practice of imposing a fine in such cases. For we have proposed to ourselves to give here the reason for the precepts mentioned in the Law, and not for that which is stated in the Talmud. I have, however, an explanation for the interpretation given in the Talmud, but it will be communicated vivâ voce.**

Do you know, or have an idea of, what was the "explanation" of the RamBam ?

Comment: Dunno, but I think that the Ibn Ezra suggests that in "דיני שמים" - in the Heavenly Court - he _deserves_ to lose whatever he destroyed in the other person. The human court can only impose monetary damages. https://www.sefaria.org/Ibn_Ezra_on_Exodus.21.24.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: By the way, some of the mefarshim in sefaria there understood that the _following phrase_ (that you did not quote) was more-or-less an explanation of what he meant.

Comment: Sforno says similarly -- he deserves to lose an eye, but violence is incredibly difficult to titrate, so we do money instead.

Comment: @MichoelR I do not think that the pshat of the Rambam is like the Ibn Ezra / Sforno, that he deserves this midinei shammaim, because that wouldn't be something so shocking that he needs to tell him "vivâ voce" ; as per the following phrase, that does not really seems to be what the rambam says.

Comment: @EzrielS Not sure what you mean by the last line of your comment.

Comment: @MichoelR I meant that what you brought from mefarshim from Sefaria doesn't really match with the words of the Rambam as far as i understand them.

Comment: @EzrielS Not for me to say. But I did find those words of the Rambam kinda out of place, so maybe he was hinting at something?